# Why won't Eclipse remember my launch configuration?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-3.6

I am using Eclipse 3.6 Helios on Windows.

Lately, my Eclipse install has been behaving erratically when I attempt to run/debug programs. In the past, Eclipse launched my project with the most recently used configuration whenever I pressed (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>)<kbd>F11</kbd> while in an editor window for a file within the particular project.

I've set up a simple test project (for an Android app, but it's the same for a regular Java application) and set up the proper configuration, but each time I attempt to run/debug it, Eclipse asks me what kind of application this is, and I have to manually select a configuration from a list (which includes options such as "JavaScript," which do not apply to any of my projects).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107251/make-eclipse-debug-my-android-project/5630785#5630785) for instructions how to set Eclipse to launch the last used configuration.

The settings panel for this configuration is at **workspace preferences / run-debug / launching**